# switch from mysql to mysqli Undefined variable: connect

Tags: php, mysqli

I would like to switch from `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*` because I've read, that soon `mysql_*` won't be supported anymore.

Now I have a problem, that the functions which I wrote dont work anymore.

At the index.php file I have

```
global $connect;
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', "username", "password");
```

and at the functions.php file I have

```
function count_total_messages(){
        $result = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM database.messages WHERE uidto='".$_SESSION['userid']."' OR unameto='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
        $qry = mysqli_query($connect,$result);
        return $qry['total'];
    }
```

But I get the following error:

> Undefined variable: connect

What should I do? Everywhere the `mysqli_query` works except those from the functions.php file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function count_total_messages(){
        global $connect;  //You need a locally defined connect variable
        $result = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM database.messages WHERE uidto='".$_SESSION['userid']."' OR unameto='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
        $qry = mysqli_query($connect,$result);
        return $qry['total'];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the `global` the wrong way around. In your index you just need

```
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', "username", "password");
```

And in your functions you use this:

```
function count_total_messages(){
    global $connect;
    $result = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM database.messages WHERE uidto='".$_SESSION['userid']."' OR unameto='".$_SESSION['username']."'";
    $qry = mysqli_query($connect,$result);
    return $qry['total'];
}
```